# Was there widespread voter fraud in Michigan in the 2020 Presidential Elections?

Tags: united-states, politics, us-elections-2020

[Vosiznies (VINnews)](https://vinnews.com/2023/11/23/stunning-new-video-seems-to-confirm-massive-voter-fraud-in-michigan-and-expose-ag-as-liar/), a right-leaning Orthodox Jewish news site, has claimed that there has been

> disturbing and sizable evidence of systemic voter
> fraud in Michigan.

They cite a video that they claim has been unearthed by Freedom of Information
requests. It is ostensibly an interview made the Muskegan Michigan Voter
Registration Fraud Investigation with an employee of GBI Strategies
from August 2020.

She claims that there were a lot of fake addresses on the voter registrations
she received via canvassers.

VINNews continues:

> These now substantiated allegations show widespread, systemic, ongoing
> voter registration fraud in a major swing state in the 2020 elections,
> and major Democrats in Law Enforcement knew it.

The 30 minute video (with excerpts) was [posted on Twitter/X](https://twitter.com/yehuda_miller/status/1726700709310091747) by Yehuda Miller,
Bergen County New Jersey Republican County Committee Member.

Was there systemic voter fraud in Michigan? Does the video provide evidence?

Comment: I don't think you can possibly get the answer you seem to be hoping for. People's *opinions* are off-topic here, and the official answer is investigations are ongoing (according to the same article). The video provides *some evidence*, but a single witness who is raising a red flag about some odd paperwork isn't likely to be sufficient proof for a trial. Meanwhile [yes, there have been prosecutions for election anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_prosecution_of_fake_electors).

Comment: @Oddthinking thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Oddthinking I believe a fair answer would be that there may have been some incorrect addresses, but that does not show the election was stolen.

Comment: FWTW the VINnews claim this has been ignored seems false https://www.fox17online.com/news/local-news/lakeshore/muskegon/documents-detail-msp-investigation-into-alleged-muskegon-area-voter-fraud

Comment: @TheAsh: That sounds like a personal opinion. It might be reasonable, but personal opinions are not what people are here for. If they were, they would go to Reddit.

Comment: @Oddthinking: https://www.newsweek.com/fact-check-did-michigan-police-uncover-2020-democratic-election-plot-1820154 might actually be answerable to that extent but is a newspaper a better source? That's about the more widely covered FOIA-obtained documents (see my prev comment) rather than the video/interview, but the substance of the claim seems to be the same. The clerck mentioned in that Newsweek piece is probably the person we see interviewed.

Comment: @Fizz: That certainly gave more context (e.g. who GBI Strategies were) and helped me understand the claim. so maybe it is a good base for the answer. Ultimately, we have Newsweek saying "We believe the official story and here it is." and VINnews saying "The official story is false, and here is a video that proves it," I can't see how the video is inconsistent with the official story, but that is personal opinion with not much research; maybe others can point out the flaws.

Comment: Is the claim about "voter fraud" (that is, actual fraudulent votes) or just "voter registration fraud" (which doesn't result in fraudulent votes if caught)?

Comment: @Laurel the latter